# Should we make a `gboard` tag alias to `google-keyboard` or vice versa?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Recently, I believe Google renamed their keyboard to Gboard.

Should we make a [gboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gboard) tag and alias it to [google-keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-keyboard)? Or should we do the opposite?

Comment: Would help with confusion. I don't see why not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added the synonym `gboard` to [google-keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-keyboard).  We can reverse the direction later if we find there is confusion.